# custom component not installed correctly in joomla 1.5.x

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

recently i have made a custom blog component for our client, in my localhost it works perfectly now i have to prepare a package for this component for our client to give him this component. I prepare the package according to this link

http://docs.joomla.org/Components:xml_installfile

**HERE is XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<install type="component" version="1.5.0">
  <name>customblog</name>
  <author>Jogesh Sharma</author>
  <creationDate>March 2013</creationDate>
  <copyright>Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>
  <license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>
  <authorEmail>hello@webomnizz.com</authorEmail>
  <authorUrl>http://webomnizz.com</authorUrl>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
  <description>This component manage all the Blog sections!</description>
  <installfile>install.customblog.php</installfile>
  <uninstallfile>uninstall.customblog.php</uninstallfile>
  <files>
      <filename>customblog.php</filename>
      <filename>customblog.html.php</filename>
      <filename>images/style.css</filename>
      <filename>images/plus-icon.png</filename>
      <filename>images/twitter-icon.png</filename>
      <filename>images/facebook-icon.png</filename>
  </files>

  <install>
      <sql>
          <file driver="mysql">install.mysql.sql</file>
      </sql>
  </install>

  <uninstall>
      <sql>
          <file driver="mysql">uninstall.mysql.sql</file>
      </sql>
  </uninstall>


  <administration>
      <menu img="js/ThemeOffice/component.png">Blog Component</menu>
      <submenu>
          <menu link="option=com_customblog">Blog</menu>
      </submenu>

      <files>
          <filename>install.mysql.sql</filename>
          <filename>uninstall.mysql.sql</filename>
          <filename>admin.customblog.php</filename>
          <filename>admin.customblog.html.php</filename>
          <filename>toolbar.customblog.php</filename>
          <filename>toolbar.customblog.html.php</filename>
          <filename>admin.customblog.php</filename>
          <filename>index.html</filename>
          <filename>tables/customblog.php</filename>
      </files>
  </administration>
</install>
```

Here is the screenshoot for component directory structure: 
[image]

But after converting in zip file, when i tried to install my component i got the strange ERROR:

```
JInstaller::install: There is already a folder called 'C:\wamp\www\joom_new\administrator\components\com_customblog\admin.customblog.php'. Please initially check whether:
• the Extension is already installed
• the file names in the XML file are spelled correctly
• there are no XML files listed inside the extension.xml file
• all of the files (not including XML files) are correctly listed in the extension.xml file and there are no duplicate entries
• there is an empty folder listed from a previous installation attempt
```

I don't know what is missing, i installed separate joomla1.5.x and then tried to install on that then getting stuck in this problem, can anyone please help me to rid these errors??

I am using joomla 1.5.26 cause my client need in this version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You included twice

```
<filename>admin.customblog.php</filename>
```

in administration section.

And the "strange" error actually told you what was wrong

> Please initially check whether:
>
> - all of the files (not including XML files) are correctly listed in the extension.xml file and there are no duplicate entries